# DisplayLink Driver on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have purchased a [Wavlink WL-UG39DK1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019XOJ874) and I can't get the displays to work. My displays do not receive a signal. The USB devices and audio works fine. I installed the drivers from [here](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu). Not sure what else to do here. Has anyone worked with DisplayLink drivers?

Comment: G'day Mate Did you manage to get this working? I have also installed the DisplayLink driver but cannot work out what to do next. Plugging in the USB cable didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The website does offer other versions under the "Legacy Drivers" section of the Ubuntu page going back to 17.10 if that's the edition you're running.

The support is much better for 20.04 LTS or any long-term support edition.

If your BIOS allows it, you may extend the boot time so that external graphical hardware can sync up with the DisplayLink solution.